# Refering to a tableview in mainstoryboard

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm making a new custom view controller class programmatically that has a table view in it. I'm trying to assign this table view with a custom cell class that I made.

```
class AllTasksViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    let tableview = UITableView()
    
    // Number of Rows
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return coreTasks.count
        }
        
        
        // Cell Data and Configuration
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let task = coreTasks[indexPath.row]
            
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell") as! CustomCell // Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I'm getting a nil value I think it's because I need to specify which tableView has an identifier "taskCell" in the storyboard. how do I do that?

here is the custom cell Class

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
 
    
    @IBOutlet var taskLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var dateLabel: UILabel!
    //    @IBOutlet var iconsCell: UIImageView!
    


    func setTask(task: NSManagedObject ){
        taskLabel.text = task.value(forKey: "name") as? String // this is giving me nil value
        dateLabel.text = task.value(forKey: "date") as? String

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your tableViewCell class for this table view to be able to use it. Do it in viewDidLoad or any time before the first data load to the tableView

```
class AllTasksViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    let tableview = UITableView()
    
    func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       tableView.dataSource = self
       tableView.delegate = self

       self.view.addSubView(tableView)

        
       tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"taskCell")

       tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // Number of Rows
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return coreTasks.count
        }
        
        
    // Cell Data and Configuration
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let task = coreTasks[indexPath.row]
            
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell") as! CustomCell
```

Comment: @CharlesLenx I modified the answer. Try something like that. If it is registered, it should't be nil when dequeuing

Comment: the function setValue from the class CustomCell is still giving me nil value somehow